# Readers' Feedback on Accepted Answer

Tags: discussion

Question or answer readers may give their up-voting or down-voting without revealing their opinion. This rule is known to me. I have faced one experience. Here, I had discussed with OP for about half an hour regarding his requirements. Accordingly, I had edited his question properly so that all readers will be aware of exact question requirements. Later, I have written the answer. OP has accepted it. After acceptance of the [answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/19200/21996), I have faced down-voting [-2]. [I am already aware of all the rules about how to write good question and answer also]. I can't understand what may be the problem in my answer.

**Note** - OP has implemented my guidelines in his real life scenario and he succeeded in that. That mean he is happy with the answer. **Proof** - Please see the last comment of OP.

Comment: Just FYI: If I recall correctly, you answered that question while it was still off-topic. It's very common that answers on questions that have closing votes casted (and therefore are likely to get closed soon) get downvotes because we assume such questions shouldn't be answered yet for they're not a good fit for their stack. What happened here may be that your answer got DVs, the question got fixed and became on-topic, but people who casted DVs on your answer didn't withdraw their votes.

Comment: I really like this IPS site. I have joined and I am finding my-self relaxed after solving other's problems (by giving answers). If these are the irrelevant things happening on IPS, then I have to give up and need go delete my account.

Comment: Getting downvotes is something you can't avoid, no matter how good and useful your contributions are. We could discuss it further in chat if you want to? I feel that this comment I made is not worth an answer but I'd be glad to discuss it with you :)

Comment: @avazula, Before closing it (by 5 members), I have edited it properly (so that it should not be closed). I had talked on chat also for requesting -- please do not close it. Still One member told me that it is off topic. I have convinced properly that it is not off-topic. Nobody has replied for my that 'convincing' comment. Later it has opened (as per my expectations). After acceptance of the answer, it has got down-voted.

Comment: I was quite sure that it is not off-topic question. But, It has by mistakenly got closed. So, I dared to write an answer.

Comment: @DDD the question is still off-topic: *I want to find an excuse perhaps, a very good excuse in such that I can make her give me a second chance before she verifies my work and put a mark on class’s catalog.*. See our [help/on-topic], questions asking for us to create their arguments are off-topic.

Comment: specifically: *If you are having a dispute with your spouse or coworker, we are not going to settle the dispute for you or give you points to argue.* The edits certainly obfuscate this point, but it's still asking about that, and it's still off-topic.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell, But then there should be down-votes for question also (mainly).

Comment: @DDD true. But we can't control what the community chooses to vote...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell and avazula, If question is off-topic then mainly there should be negative (more) voting for OP's question. Now, at this moment, I see here after putting my this meta question and comments, I am getting more down-voting and that is not for question but that is for my answer. Because may be I have asked this meta request genuinely.

Comment: Now, again un-downvoted (or upvoted) after this comment. This proves that it is certain kind of revenge. I respect your opinions, you hard work for this site. But, I find that seriously I am wasting my time. Thanks for your feedback and comments for my this question.

Comment: @DDD We can't always be agreeable to everyone in the world.  Someone is always going to disagree with your answer.  I have an answer with nearly 200 upvotes that *still* has downvotes on it.  Pay more attention to the net score and not the fact that it's being downvoted and you'll be a lot happier.  No one has  a personal vendetta against you and is voting for revenge.

Answer (score 5):

You say in your question: *[I am already aware of all the rules about how to write good question and answer also]*. And in the comments you make the following claim: *Before closing it (by 5 members), I have edited it properly (so that it should not be closed). I had talked on chat also for requesting -- please do not close it.*

I am not so sure your claims about being aware of what makes a good question, and editing this to be completely on-topic, are absolutely true. Although the edits obfuscate the initial problem a little, the question still doesn't look entirely on-topic to me. It's still asking about us to make an excuse for them:

> I want to find an excuse perhaps, a very good excuse in such that I can make her give me a second chance before she verifies my work and put a mark on class’s catalog.

This is in accordance with the [first revision](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/revisions/19197/1):

> Question: What To Say to the teacher in such that she can grant me a second chance?

These kinds of 'phrasing requests' or requests for us to make someone's argument for them have been off-topic for a while now. From our [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions asking about

> If you are having a dispute with your spouse or coworker, we are not going to settle the dispute for you or give you points to argue.

and:

> ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say.

are considered off-topic and not a good fit for IPS. Your edits here don't really show you being aware of this, or you would have edited it to no longer ask/mention the part about finding an excuse.

I think the question might have been saved with some proper editing, as the OP has set out some 'arguments' already in their three labeled points. I'd still ask what was tried or not, and why those thoughts were discarded or approaches didn't work, which is also one of the things outlined in our requirements for [good questions](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/1599), as right now it's still kind of opaque exactly what an answer should focus on, what part of their Interpersonal Skills the OP is struggling with.

---

> I can't understand what may be the problem in my answer.

Now onto your questions about your answer. I can't see into the heads of the people downvoting. But like Cashbee said, they may just think your proposed solution is unuseful. Personally, I see you giving the OP 4 steps to do, and sentences to say (as requested per the off-topic part of the question), yet I see you giving no explanation for **why each step you're proposing is done the way it is done**. Again, this is something we've explained about in [our guidelines on good answers](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/1599). Later in your answer, you give some reasons for why to follow these points, which basically boils down to 'doing this will convince your teacher', but yet again you fail to explain (or get across) **why this specific way of doing things will do so**.

You're also making an assumption without proof, which is that no teacher will let you fail on a project but they will always extend your deadline with 1 or 2 days. I'd personally like to see some proof of this claim, as I have direct experience to the contrary.

The last point for me is that your use of English severely diminishes the readability of your answers. I've seen you asking for spell-checks in chat, but the grammar and spelling of this answer still make it hard to read. Community members are generally willing to help, but after editing so many posts of yours, they might very well become tired of endlessly correcting the same mistakes and just downvote and move on. Especially with the rate you're answering questions (you've written 6 answers in the past two days, 25 in the past 2 weeks), you can't really expect community members to not realize they've already corrected the same mistakes in your posts over and over and becoming perhaps a bit tired of doing so.

---

As for your comments:

> If question is off-topic then mainly there should be negative (more) voting for OP's question. Now, at this moment, I see here after putting my this meta question and comments, I am getting more down-voting and that is not for question but that is for my answer. Because may be I have asked this meta request genuinely.

You may have asked the meta genuinely, but asking on meta does carry a risk of people looking at your answer and thinking 'this deserves a downvote indeed'. That's a sad reality, but nothing we can (or should) stop. It's the same as asking about closing or reopening of a question on meta, it carries a risk that people disagree and vote accordingly.

As for the voting on the question, votes don't say a lot on IPS yet. A better alternative to looking to votes for knowing quality (for now) still is familiarizing yourself even more with the guidelines on good questions and good answers than judging by voting for now.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes we just have to live with the fact that even your answer helped the OP, the userbase dislikes your answer and votes accordingly. Having the answer accepted by the OP doesn't mean everybody else likes it too. The popularity of an answer can help OP to filter "good" from "bad" answers, but it is still up to him alone to decide which answer to accept.

Personally, I don't agree with your approach of letting the mother make a phone call and I suspect this could be one of the causes for your downvotes. But then again, I am one of those who still think the whole question is off topic so I did not vote at all.

Comment: I suggested Mother's phone call at very extreme situation. It will obviously save OP from further failing in that subject. Parents should know the fact and it indicates that OP used to talk with his parents on his study matters.