# Can this post be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I have a question about my Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange post: [Why people are often mad at me with I having no idea why they're mad?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/why-people-are-often-mad-at-me-with-i-having-no-idea-why-theyre-mad)

I did additional edits. I know some people will be mad at me. However, why so many?

Comment: I still stand by my original comment there: Adding the context did not make the post more about Interpersonal Skills and any less opinionated: We can't really see what the people that wrote their reactions there are thinking, such questions are off-topic on IPS. Take up the matter of your ban with the sites you are banned on, they have the full details and can likely explain to you why you were banned and what you need to do to be unbanned.

Answer (score 10):

I can see several issues with that post.

You copied a large part, if not the whole thread, of content from another site and you don't explain what you think the problem is. So before anything, people have to read the whole thread and try to understand the context, situation and potential issues from it. That is not very user-friendly toward the potential people who would try to answer your question. I know chances are that you copied the whole thread because it was deleted on the site it came from, but it would have been better to rather explain what happened and why you think your post was badly received there.

Now the main issue with your question is that you're asking "what exactly is wrong with that thread?", **which is off-topic here**. We can't read people's minds, we don't (and can't) know why they did what they did. That's not only true for your post, it is true to all questions asking "why did X react that way when I did Y".

Finally, I think your post then got deleted because besides being off-topic, it sounded like a rant toward the moderating community of another website. Like one of IPS' moderators advised you, I think you should directly **ask the site's mods** to know what they think was wrong with your post. They're the one who can tell you why it was removed.

Now, I don't think your question is salvageable through editing because I don't think we could turn the question "why did X react that way when I told then Y" into something that would be on-topic for IPS. If you'd like to ask another question in the future, I invite you to check [our tour](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour), our [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help) and our [faq about questions](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/21067)- this should help you have a clear idea of what you can ask here and how to phrase it. Don't hesitate to reach at us if you need any help too.